# How to Handle DMA ADC's with HAL with software triggering

Tags: interrupt, stm32, dma, adc, stm32f4

I want to use the benefits of DMA for transfering a bunch of channels on an ADC, and that's working just fine.  I'm able to transfer the data, they are continuously updated without any supervision in my little array..all good.

The problem I have is that I want to only do these conversions in an interrupt (these are fast conversions compared to what I'm timing with my PWMs and OC timers, so that's not an issue), cherry pick the measurement I want and then use it later..

However, I have no idea if what I've got in the array at any given time is in fact what I'm expecting it to be, because I don't know where the DMA and the ADC are at in their conversion/transfer process.

Basically, I want to read the ADC after the high pulse of a PWM has been asserted on a GPIO and then I want to read the ADC after the low pulse of a PWM has been asserted on the same GPIO.  Then, in a switch case/state machine type of thing, I want to compare their difference, and if it's small enough (the two values are close to each other), then I do some stuff.

This is what I want:

```
void FallingEdgeofPWMCallbackFunction(type whatever)
{
Set GPIO pins Low
Get an ADC measurement and DMA that over to the low_ADCValues[] array
Stop writing over low_ADCValues[]...Once is plenty.
}

void RisingEdgeofPWMCallbackFunction(type whatever)
    {
    Set GPIO pins High
    Get an ADC measurement and DMA that over to the high_ADCValues[] array
    Stop writing over high_ADCValues[]...Once is plenty.
    Switch Case State machine ...
    ..
    compare high_ADCValues and low_ADCValues and then do stuff.    
    ..
    }
```

And here's the code for the interrupt source that CubeMX generates...This is the code that ain't gettin' it done.

```
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_it.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
//#include "PWM.h"
#include "extern.h"
#include "motor.h"
#include "adc.h"
int pwm = 0;
unsigned int fade = 100;
int current_phase = 0;
int v_gnd = 0;
int low_ADC=0;
int flux = 0;
int windup = 0;
int b_zero_detected = 0;
#define START_TIME 100
#define THRESHOLD 10
#define ZERO_DETECTED 10
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/* External variables --------------------------------------------------------*/
extern DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;
extern TIM_HandleTypeDef htim3;
extern TIM_HandleTypeDef htim4;

/******************************************************************************/
/*            Cortex-M4 Processor Interruption and Exception Handlers         */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
* @brief This function handles Non maskable interrupt.
*/
void NMI_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN NonMaskableInt_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END NonMaskableInt_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN NonMaskableInt_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END NonMaskableInt_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles Hard fault interrupt.
*/
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN HardFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN HardFault_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END HardFault_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles Memory management fault.
*/
void MemManage_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN MemoryManagement_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END MemoryManagement_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN MemoryManagement_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END MemoryManagement_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles Pre-fetch fault, memory access fault.
*/
void BusFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN BusFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END BusFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN BusFault_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END BusFault_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles Undefined instruction or illegal state.
*/
void UsageFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN UsageFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END UsageFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN UsageFault_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END UsageFault_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles System service call via SWI instruction.
*/
void SVC_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SVCall_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SVCall_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SVCall_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SVCall_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles Debug monitor.
*/
void DebugMon_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DebugMonitor_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DebugMonitor_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DebugMonitor_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DebugMonitor_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles Pendable request for system service.
*/
void PendSV_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PendSV_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END PendSV_IRQn 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN PendSV_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END PendSV_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles System tick timer.
*/
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_IncTick();
  HAL_SYSTICK_IRQHandler();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 1 */
}

/******************************************************************************/
/* STM32F4xx Peripheral Interrupt Handlers                                    */
/* Add here the Interrupt Handlers for the used peripherals.                  */
/* For the available peripheral interrupt handler names,                      */
/* please refer to the startup file (startup_stm32f4xx.s).                    */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
* @brief This function handles TIM3 global interrupt.
*/
void TIM3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim3);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM3_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM3_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles TIM4 global interrupt.
*/
void TIM4_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim4);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM4_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM4_IRQn 1 */
}

/**
* @brief This function handles DMA2 stream0 global interrupt.
*/
void DMA2_Stream0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_adc1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2_Stream0_IRQn 1 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  if(htim == &htim4){
    GPIOC->ODR |= phase_mask[current_phase];
    HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
    HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*)ADCValue,10);
    if(windup>=START_TIME){
      switch(current_phase)
      {
        case 0:
          if(ADCValue[0]-low_ADC<ZERO_DETECTED){
            b_zero_detected=1;
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, LED_Pin);
          }
          if(b_zero_detected){
            flux+=ADCValue[0];
          }
          if(flux >= THRESHOLD){
            current_phase = 1;
            flux = 0;
            b_zero_detected=0;
          }
          break;

        case 1:
          if(ADCValue[1]-low_ADC<ZERO_DETECTED){
            b_zero_detected=1;
          }
          if(b_zero_detected){
            flux+=ADCValue[1];
          }
          if(flux >= THRESHOLD){
            current_phase = 2;
            flux = 0;
            b_zero_detected=0;
          }
          break;
        case 2:
          if(ADCValue[2]-low_ADC<ZERO_DETECTED){
            b_zero_detected=1;
          }
          if(b_zero_detected){
            flux+=ADCValue[2];
          }
          if(flux >= THRESHOLD){
            current_phase = 3;
            flux = 0;
            b_zero_detected=0;
          }
          break;
        case 3:
          if(ADCValue[0]-low_ADC<ZERO_DETECTED){
            b_zero_detected=1;
          }
          if(b_zero_detected){
            flux+=ADCValue[0];
          }
          if(flux >= THRESHOLD){
            current_phase = 4;
            flux = 0;
            b_zero_detected=0;
          }
          break;
        case 4:
          if(ADCValue[1]-low_ADC<ZERO_DETECTED){
            b_zero_detected=1;
          }
          if(b_zero_detected){
            flux+=ADCValue[1];
          }
          if(flux >= THRESHOLD){
            current_phase = 5;
            flux = 0;
            b_zero_detected=0;
          }
          break;
        case 5:
          if(ADCValue[2]-low_ADC<ZERO_DETECTED){
            b_zero_detected=1;
          }
          if(b_zero_detected){
            flux+=ADCValue[2];
          }
          if(flux >= THRESHOLD){
            current_phase = 0;
            flux = 0;
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;

      }
  HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);
    }
  }

  if (htim == &htim3){
    if (windup < START_TIME){
    current_phase++;
    if (current_phase > 5){current_phase = 0;}
    windup++;
    }
  }
}

void HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*)ADCValue,10);
  //if(htim == &htim4){
    GPIOC->ODR &= 0x00;
//    HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*)ADCValue,10);
      switch(current_phase)
      {
        case 0:
          low_ADC=ADCValue[0];
          break;
        case 1:
          low_ADC=ADCValue[1];
          break;
        case 2:
          low_ADC=ADCValue[2];
          break;
        case 3:
          low_ADC=ADCValue[0];
          break;
        case 4:
          low_ADC=ADCValue[1];
          break;
        case 5:
          low_ADC=ADCValue[2];
          break;
        default:
          break;

      }
      HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);

}
```

Comment: It is extremely easy to archive when you do not use the HAL :) only bare registers. You program the EXTEN and  bits and EXTSEL bits in the ADC configuration register and you are done in one line of the code. You can also use the timer triggered by the PWM if you do not want to read ADC at every change. IMO I do not see any benefits of HALm as it makes simple task difficult (I think it should be right opposite)

Comment: Ok, thanks... So, I can handle it similarly to how I've handled the GPIOC ODR?

Comment: ODR is a GPIO register. HAL veils it and makes it "hardware independent" (lol). Just use the registers. Chose the correct event and you are done.

Comment: Do I need to do anything to DMA, or just leave him alone?

Comment: You need to configure it as well of course

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at those configuration registers